# Xen fails to boot (timeout mounting /dev/sda2)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, debian, xen

I am new to Xen and trying to follow the guide from the [Debian Wiki's Xen entry](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen#Installation_on_squeeze). I have installed squeeze on a VMware Workstation image with plenty of space. The file storage is over LVM.

My newly installed guest OS does not boot -- the busybox bootloader timesout and fails. Here's the exact error:

```
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Waiting for root file system ... done.
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/sda2 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
```

How can I make my Debian Squeeze guest OS boot on Xen 4?

All the salient info I can think of:

**Guest creation:**

```
root@debxentest:/etc/xen-tools# xen-create-image --hostname xenguest1 --scsi --vcpus 1 --pygrub --dist squeeze

General Information
--------------------
Hostname       :  xenguest1
Distribution   :  squeeze
Mirror         :  http://localmirror/debian/
Partitions     :  swap            64Mb  (swap)
                  /               4Gb   (ext3)
Image type     :  full
Memory size    :  64Mb
Kernel path    :  /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64
Initrd path    :  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64

Networking Information
----------------------
IP Address     : DHCP [MAC: 00:16:3E:1A:8D:68]


Creating swap on /dev/universe/xenguest1-swap
Done

Creating ext3 filesystem on /dev/universe/xenguest1-disk
Done
Installation method: debootstrap
Done

Running hooks
Done

No role scripts were specified.  Skipping

Creating Xen configuration file
Done
Setting up root password
Generating a password for the new guest.
All done


Logfile produced at:
     /var/log/xen-tools/xenguest1.log

Installation Summary
---------------------
Hostname        :  xenguest1
Distribution    :  squeeze
IP-Address(es)  :  dynamic
RSA Fingerprint :  e3:6e:87:8b:59:78:9d:4d:3b:7f:b2:84:48:95:98:36
Root Password   :  Wppn4eKf
```

**LVM setup (volumes and groups):**

```
  lvm> lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/universe/xenguest1-swap
  VG Name                universe
  LV UUID                r68Qej-hVOE-ZRMu-KRzU-cXi4-paHN-4FCM0n
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                64.00 MiB
  Current LE             16
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/universe/xenguest1-disk
  VG Name                universe
  LV UUID                LBZpOl-sHjU-ec3d-zePZ-B2Nv-eLQ3-1pJeJ6
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/debxentest/root
  VG Name                debxentest
  LV UUID                XlMXTu-8IEQ-Ec0P-3kaw-menW-Dcz8-Qmu6Ea
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                18.91 GiB
  Current LE             4840
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/debxentest/swap_1
  VG Name                debxentest
  LV UUID                VJkXmY-kr7D-Rvvv-Ekg2-vo54-f8D0-hXGDYr
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                872.00 MiB
  Current LE             218
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:1

  lvm> vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               debxentest
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               19.76 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5058
  Alloc PE / Size       5058 / 19.76 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               1tEMNQ-B81G-82nb-SCXq-mNJR-Swh7-UGXV14

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               universe
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               20.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5119
  Alloc PE / Size       1040 / 4.06 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       4079 / 15.93 GiB
  VG UUID               vxAIfs-wMIT-Nxcc-gEOh-oSoY-e5Zx-r2VTum
```

**Xen Setup**

```
root@debxentest:/home/tester# xm list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0   941     1     r-----     22.4
xenguest1                                    2    64     1     -b----      1.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am experiencing this exact same problem with both squeeze and wheezy.

If you are using xen-tools and xen-create-image, you can either:

- Create an image using lenny:

  xen-create-image --hostname len1 --scsi --dist lenny
- Create a squeeze image without using the scsi option:

  xen-create-image --hostname sqz1 --dist squeeze

I find this situation very odd. It seems like the scsi option should be supported by squeeze and lenny; maybe a problem with udev? As the [Debian Xen Wiki page](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen) states:

> The --scsi makes sure the VM uses normal SCSI HD names like sda. When creating a Ubuntu Maverick image, for instance, it won't boot without this option, because the default is xvda. xvda is used to make it clear it is a virtualized disk, but a non-xen kernel, like a stock pv_ops one in Ubuntu, doesn't know what those are (see notes below about the xen-blkfront driver for this, though). You can also set scsi=1 in /etc/xen-tools/xen-tools.conf to make this default.

Later on, it also states:

> The new 2.6.32 kernel images have paravirt_ops-based Xen dom0 and domU support. When you create an image for Ubuntu Maverick, which includes a kernel that has pv_ops, it will therefore not use a Xen kernel, but the Ubuntu stock one, as it is capable of running on Xen's hypervisor.
>
> For those who want to test the 2.6.32 kernel domU on an earlier dom0, you have to make sure that the xen-blkfront domU driver is loaded, and can find the root and other disk partitions. This is no longer the case if you still use the deprecated hda* or sda* device names in domU .cfg files. Switch to xvda* devices, which also work with 2.6.18 and 2.6.26 dom0 kernels.

I have confirmed that the --scsi option works with Maverick, which uses a 2.6.35 kernel, but that shouldn't matter. This all seems contradictory.

This link may also help:

- http://wiki.debian.org/PyGrub

Comment: I ended up simply not using the --scsi option for squeeze guests. I was able to make changes to the domu.cfg file, referencing xvd(a|b), and installing grub in the domu as described on the [Debian pygrub page](http://wiki.debian.org/PyGrub). Furthermore, I was able to install openvz in the domu, too!

Comment: Also, I should mention that my final set up was not on VMWare. I tried that initially, but was not able to get any networking functional at all. I switched to real hardware, and then ran into the hanging issue.